Add related value to one textbox column from another textbox column autocompleted with MS Access
I have two textboxes.
One is an autocompleted textbox (Textbox1) from MS Access database (autocompleting from the table name "Stock" and column name "Description").
I want the second Textbox (Textbox2) to display corresponding item (column name "Rate") to the first Textbox (Textbox1).
Both values are from same table(table name "Stock") and two columns (one is "Description" and another one is "Rate"). Here is the code of autocomplete textbox, added to form (form1) load event.
con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Database\MSDB.accdb"
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select Description from Stock", con)
Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
Dim ds As New DataSet
da.Fill(ds)
Dim column1 As New AutoCompleteStringCollection
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
    column1.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("Description").ToString())
Next
TextBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = column1
TextBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest

I want to add Textbox2 value ("Rate") with the Textbox1 leave event.

Have you tried a database query to get the data for TextBox2 in the Textbox1 leave event handler?

Yes I tried now, and problem resolved. Thanks to every one who is trying to help me.

The query is used in Textbox1 leave event is = Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select * From Stock where Description= '" & TextBox1.Text & "'", con)
